# Layout of "Next tag badge" selector is broken on half screen

Tags: bug

If you tile your browser window into a vertically split 1080p monitor, the selection dialogs for the next tag badge and the other "Next badge" (whatever that is called) are broken.

By default, the <s>red freehand circle</s> selection dialog is not fully in view, and the horizontal scrollbar does not appear.
[image: Unscrolled]

If you scroll to the right before opening, the entire thing is visible, but the background color is messed up.
[image: Scrolled]